# How to simulate a user using Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to get the content's of a specific page, but it requires me to login. So my first question is how do a post request with JSON data. And my next question is if I just do post/get request from node will it keep a session for me? Or do I have to something special to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will generally need to implement a cookie jar. [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request) does this for you.

So all you need to do is turn the cookie jar on, make a HTTP request to `service/login`, then your session should be logged in. Now make a HTTP request to `service/doStuff` and do the stuff you need to do.